# Blender - Intersection between 2 objects deletes part of my first object

Tags: boolean, blender, intersection, modifier

I'm making a chess piece (a bishop) and I am trying to make the top notch.
For this purpose, I made a new cube, resized it and put on the place to make the cut.

I want to make a cut using a modifier: Boolean, intersecting the two objects.

The problem I am facing is that while intersecting, the top UV Sphere that simulates the 'hat' of the bishop disappears.
What I did so far:
- Remove Doubles
- CTRL+J to join Bishop+Hat(UV Sphere) to make 1 component

Nothing helped and when trying to intersect, the UVSphere-hat disappears.

Why? How to solve?

Here is the bishop before modifier, with hat:
Here is the .blend file to catch the problem faster:
Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: The Images and links were cut out. Sorry but I am still new at SO. [Image before](http://i.imgur.com/7B7my5q.png) | [Image after](http://i.imgur.com/eiTWJop.png) | [.blend File](https://mega.nz/#!21YkgLCJ!wZM_z7c40Ut-W_MyOungnUxtrIw_y7UXGLYY7Hhxgcg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean modifier offers two different solvers that produce different results. You want the intersect operation with the carve solver. You also want to hide the cube that you are using for the intersection otherwise you won't see the hole that it has cut out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it indeed makes totally sense, but my problem is that I have no 'Solver: BMesh|Carve' to choose for, just nothing with any operation chosen. You can see it in the screenshot [After] I posted. How to make those options appear? Thank you ! :)

Comment: My bad - that was added after 2.77 to be part of 2.78 (I use a current development build most of the time). The boolean modifier in 2.77 you want the difference operation and to hide the cutting object.

Comment: Actually the boolean modifier in 2.77 should match the carve solver, so you should want the difference operation and to hide the cutting object, but your mesh seems to be back to front and gives the result you want with the intersect operation. The cube you are cutting with has a negative scale which is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was the following to go straight to the point: THE CUBE HAD NEGATIVE SCALE. So if you have a similar trouble, check your objects if they have correct scale/dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Just to go straight to the point I'll add the reply here and select sambler's excellent answer as right.

In my case the Cube which was going to intersect with the bishop HAD NEGATIVE SCALE.

If you have similar problems, check if your objects scale/parameters have negative parameters